# AS3 My code delay doesn't work properly

Tags: actionscript-3, setinterval

In a function i'm trying to delay the execution of the code through:

```
var thinkTimer = setInterval(Actions(opp), C.THINK_TIME);
```

where Actions is a simple (tested working) function, opp is a small integer and C.THINK_TIME is a constant = 3000 (3 seconds).

but using setInterval I got this problem: The function Actions immediatly runs (without waiting the interval) and every 3 seconds I got this message in the output:

TypeError: Error #1009: Impossibile accedere a una proprietà o a un metodo di un riferimento oggetto null.
    at SetIntervalTimer/onTimer()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

What is this about? I'm not trying to accede a property or a function with a refering object null! :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your `Actions(opp)` call into a nested function, and supply the name of that into your `setInterval` call, like this:

```
private var opp:int; // place this outside if you ever want to change opp at runtime
// without changing the setInterval statement
function actOpp():void { Actions(opp); } // wrapper
var thinkTimer:uint = setInterval(actOpp, C.THINK_TIME);
```

The actual error is that `setInterval` wants a `Function` object, and you are trying to provide it a function output of `Actions(opp)`. Most likely your `Actions` function returns void, this causes your errors to appear.

In case you don't want to change your `opp` at runtime, say you want your AI to check for a certain opp once in a set period of time, use the extended syntax of `setInterval` like this:

```
var thinkTimer:uint = setInterval(Actions, C.THINK_TIME, opp);
```

Then you retrieve the passed `opp` value in your function using `arguments[0]` syntax, or, if you declared a parameter in that function, use its name as usual. Note that with this syntax your `opp` value passed to `Actions` will not change if you change the value of the variable elsewhere. To override, you can use a wrapper function for `opp`, pass its **name** (or reference) to the `setInterval` as a parameter, then accept that reference inside `Actions`, call the function and receive the current `opp` value.

Hope this helps, if you have questions, please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone speaks your language, but from the Error code, something is referencing a null object, one of the objects is null, trace the objects before this line and see which one is "null".